# While creating an new project in angular schematic work flow failed

Tags: angular, npm

Angular cli is successful instaled and while creating project by ng new project name that creates some packages and finnally packages installed failed and unexpected end in json while parsing near.....'A85qs.......'

Can anyone ans to my qus

Answer (score 0):

There's a high chance that your npm cache been damaged.

Try:
npm cache clean --force

Comment: I try npm cache --force bt the problem still remains same